# Relationship between windows exe and processes

Tags: windows, process, operating-system

I've been trying to understand the relationship between applications, instances, exes and processes.

When i open two different word files on my windows laptop, 2 different 'Processes' show up in Task manager. I can independently kill each one

When i open Process Explorer - I can only see 1 instance of WINWORD.exe. I can't seem to find the processes related to each of the files i opened. Can someone explain whether each file has an associated process or a single process is used to host multiple files?

Answer (score 1):

There's a mixup of several concepts here; executables, processes, what "opening a file" means and "whatever Task Manager shows in its processes tab", which is mostly a lie.

Double-clicking on a document generally<sup>1</sup> boils down to a look up on the file extension in the registry and launching the associated executable, passing the path to the clicked file as command line argument.

Whenever an executable is launched, the kernel spawns a process (which roughly means, allocates some virtual memory for it and creates its main thread of execution) and loads the executable in it ("copies"<sup>2</sup> it in memory, loads its dependencies and in general performs a lot of tasks necessary to be able to execute the machine code that is stored in it).

What happens next depends entirely on the code of the executable. Most programs will keep executing in the new process; some instead will look for an instance of the program already executing (which may or may not be the same executable), and communicate to it that a new instance has been launched (possibly forwarding to the existing instance the arguments obtained on the command line). This is generally the case for applications where there's a lot of data to share between different instances (so, to save e.g. memory) or where there's interaction between e.g. the various opened documents that is less cumbersome to implement in a single process (IPC is often a pain).

When instead you open a file e.g. from the File → Open menu of an application, that's generally done in the same process; again, when you actually click open it's up to the application to decide whether to open it inside the same process, or to spawn a different one for the other document.

The important concept here, though, is that if you see different top-level windows (≈ windows that you see in the taskbar) it does not mean they come from different processes, a single process may spawn multiple top-level windows (and indeed applications that deal with multiple files in multiple windows often do that). Also, remember that the fact that the 1 open file = 1 window (or 1 application, for what that matters) is just a GUI concept; you may have files that are handled concurrently by multiple processes (databases are a common instance of this).

As for Task Manager: the processes tab doesn't really list processes as they are seen by the system; some are grouped according to some unspecified rule/heuristics, some other processes are expanded to show sub-components (e.g. the various svchost.exe processes); processes that have multiple top-level windows, in particular, are shown "as if" having sub-processes. Clicking on "End task" on these fake sub-processes will actually send a "polite" quit request to the associated window, which will be handled in an application-specific way.

Ultimately, you shouldn't really think too hard about what is shown here. What are actually the "real" processes as understood by the operating system kernel is what is shown in the "Details" tab, which should match what you see in Process Exporer. If you do kill the process here, you'll see that all windows that are managed by it disappear.

---

1. I say "generally" because it's actually a lot more complicated than that; file association can do some really complicated stuff that avoids process creation, generally to directly communicate to an already running program that it has to load another file, essentially skipping the middleman described in the section that follows.
2. In quotes because it's smarter than that; what is generally done is a copy-on-write file mapping, which instructs the OS virtual memory manager to load the parts of the executable that are needed from disk *when they are accessed in memory*, and to copy on the fly the sections that are modified.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo for a detailed explanation. So then is it correct to think that Word executes all files in the same process since there's only a single WINWORD.exe in process explorer?

Comment: Exactly. The fact that you see two entries in Task Manager is just an artifact of how Task Manager works.